# how to make a new type in julia?

Tags: haskell, types, julia

I wrote a haskell code for translate RNA codon like this:

```
data Base = U | C | A | G
data Amino = Phe | Lue | Ile | Met | Val | Ser | Pro | Thr | Ala |
       Tyr | Stop | His | Gln | Asn | Lys | Asp | Glu | Cys | Trp | Arg | Gly deriving Show

codon :: Base -> Base -> Base -> Amino

parse :: String -> [Base]
parse = map go where
  go 'U' = U
  go 'A' = A
  go 'C' = C
  go 'G' = G

convert :: [Base] -> [Amino]
convert [] = []
convert (x1:x2:x3:xs) = codon x1 x2 x3 : convert xs
convert _ = undefined

main = do
  input <- getLine
  let x = show . convert . parse $ input
  putStrLn x

codon U U U = Phe 
codon U U C = Phe
codon U U A = Lue 
codon U U G = Lue 
codon C U U = Lue
```

And i want to write julia code like that. To make a new type like `Base` or `Amino`, i found abstract type at julia document, i couldn't find how to make a new type.

How to define new type like `Base` and `U`, `C`, `A`, `G` ?

Comment: Note that while you could directly translate this code, the more idiomatic Julia way would probalby to have `base` be a type, and have `A`, `T`, `G`, and `C` be possible values of that type. This will tend to create much faster code for Julia.

Comment: Did you read about [Composite Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Composite-Types)? Also, use a name other than `Base`, which is already reserved for the base module of code that all Julia binaries ship with.

Comment: @OscarSmith Yes, it's the solution that i want. Should you give me a keyword about how to set a possible value of the type?

Comment: @OscarSmith That's what the Haskell code does...

Comment: I don't know about Julia specifically, but generally this sort of thing is called an _enumeration_ or _enum type_, in languages that don't have as flexible algebraic data types as Haskell does.

Comment: As some of us don't know Haskell, you would have get I guess more answers if you posted instead some pseudo code of your problem. For how to write custom types: https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/language-core/custom-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is. I do not know neither genomics nor Haskell but you should like this code.

```
@enum Baze::Int8 U C A G
@enum Amino::Int8 Phe Lue Ile Met Val Ser Pro Thr Ala Tyr Stop His Gln Asn Lys Asp Glu Cys Trp Arg Gly


using Memoize
@memoize function parseS(T::Union{Type{Baze},Type{Amino}}, s::Symbol)
    dat = Dict(value => key for (key, value) in Base.Enums.namemap(T))
    T(dat[s])
end

import Base.parse
parse(T::Union{Type{Baze},Type{Amino}}, str)=parseS(T, Symbol(str))
```

Now let us see how it works. I am not sure whether you prefer 4-Tuple or perhaps a Dict for Codon anyway having this code changing is already easy.

```
julia> Codon = Tuple{Baze, Baze, Baze, Amino};

julia> codon1 = Codon(parse.(Codon.types,["U","C", "A", "Tyr"]))
(U, C, A, Tyr)

julia> codon2 = Codon(parseS.(Codon.types,[:U,:C,:A,:Tyr]))
(U, C, A, Tyr)

julia> codon3 = (U,C,A,Tyr)
(U, C, A, Tyr)

julia> codon1 === codon2 === codon3
true
```

Looks like mini genetics framework to me :-)

Comment: the hakell code translate RNA to proteins, for example, when i put the UUUUUU, the program parse this and print [Phe, Phe].
i think your code is not perfectly same as this function, but i think it's similar. Thank you!

Comment: @kn05 that is why I started my answer saying that I do not do genomics :-) However, I know of a great rapidly developing startup in Poland that is looking for this kind of folks even on junior level ;-) Anyway I guess having this Julia skeleton it should be easy to make it work correctly.